# paymentState does not change from Trial period

Tags: google-play-developer-api, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I am implementing in-app subscriptions with Google Play and synchronize the status of those through polling to Google Play API. The subscriptions have a trial period of 3 days and I expect Google API to return paymentState=0(Pending) or 1(Received) after the trial period has expired. This does not always happen for customers that have a payment failure, as Google keeps returning paymentState=0(Free trial).

It seems Google is giving a grace period, although I don't have any grace period configured for this subscription type.

Do you know why this happens and how should I update the trial period status when the 3 days of trial have expired?

Thanks

Comment: Looks similar to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135940173 for me..

Answer (score 1):

Reported this several times to google, the issue is still present, from my experience for some orders the SUBSCRIPTION_GRACE is sent >20 hours after the current cycle ends, and if you send validation request before this notification paymentState will still have value 1 or 2 instead of 0.